# TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: struct, mapping, solidity, getter

I want to have a getter for a mapping. I have this mapping and this struc:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


mapping(uint => Proyect) public proyects;

struct Proyect{
        uint id; 
        string hash; 
        string name;
        address payable author; 
    }
```

I have done this to get a tuple of the elements:

```
function getProyect(uint memory _id) public returns (uint, string, string, address){
        Proyect memory _proyect = proyects[_id];
        return(_proyect.id, _proyect.hash,_proyect.name,_proyect.author);
    }
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: Data location can only be specified for array, struct or mapping types, but "memory" was given.
    function getProyect(uint memory _id) public returns (uint, string, string, address){
                         ^-------------^

TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
    function getProyect(uint memory _id) public returns (uint, string, string, address){
                                                                ^----^

TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
    function getProyect(uint memory _id) public returns (uint, string, string, address){
                                                                        ^----^
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function getProyect(uint _id) public returns (uint, string memory, string memory, address){
        Proyect memory _proyect = proyects[_id];
        return(_proyect.id, _proyect.hash,_proyect.name,_proyect.author);
    }
```

`memory` cannot used in `uint`, and, we must add `memory` with `string`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!
Following what you said I got this without errors at the end.

```
function getProyect(uint _id) public returns (uint, string memory hs, string memory nm, address){
        Proyect memory _proyect = proyects[_id];
        hs = _proyect.hash;
        nm = _proyect.name;
        return(_proyect.id, hs, nm, _proyect.author);
    }
```